# Convergence in $l^{p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Prove that, given $q \in [1,\infty] $, then $ l^{p} \hookrightarrow l^{q} $ for all $p \in [1, q]$. Consider the sequence $ x^{(n)}=\bigl( x^{(n)}_{k} \bigr)_{k \in \mathbb{N}_{0} } \ $ defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
 x^{(n)}_{k} = (n + k)^{−1/3} \ \ \ \ n,k\in \mathbb{N}_{0} 
\end{eqnarray*}
$(i)$ For which $p \in [1,\infty] $ does the sequence $x^{(n)}$ belong to $l^{p}$? Justify the answer.

$(ii)$ Study the convergence of $x^{(n)}$ in $l^{p}$.

I'm a little confused. In the second point do I have to show the convergence with $n$ to $\infty$ or with a fixed $n$ and $k$ to $\infty$ ?

Comment: In the first point, you're asked to show that, for a fixed $n$, the sequence of $k$ given by $(n + k)^{-1/3}$ belongs to $\ell^p$ (well, you had to find the valid values of $p$ too). These sequences (e.g. $(2 + k)^{-1/3}$) are **points** in $\ell^p$. There's a different point for each $n$. In the second part, you're supposed to be stringing these **points** in $\ell^p$ into a sequence, and examining its convergence with respect to the $\ell^p$ norm.

Comment: Is "Prove that, given $q \in [1,\infty] $, then $ l^{p} \hookrightarrow l^{q} $ for all $p \in [1, q]$" part of the question? Or are you just interested in (i) and (ii)?

Comment: Thank you! I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{(n)}\in l^{p}$ iff $\sum_k \frac 1 {(n+k)^{p/3}} <\infty$. This is true iff $p >3$. When $p >3$ we can apply DCT to conclude that $\sum_k \frac 1 {(n+k)^{p/3}}  \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ since the terms are dominated by those of the convergent series $\sum \frac 1 {k^{p/3}}$. Hence $x^{(n)} \to 0$ in the space $l^{p}$ whenever $p >3$.

Comment: Thank you! Really clear

Comment: @Optimizazze It seems that Kavi's answer completely answered your question. You should accept it, by pressing the grey tick mark to the left of the answer.